# How to interpret 家居家装 in ...在服装配饰、护理美容、消费电子及家居家装这四大领域的产品上?

Tags: grammar

> 从商品类别来看，网购用户指出主要集中在服装配饰、护理美容、消费电子及家居家装这四大领域的产品上。

How to interpret '家居家装'? What does it actually mean or include?

Comment: it means 'home furnishings'

Comment: household furnishings?

Answer (score 2):

居 means to live, 装 means to decorate. 家居家装 in this sentence means the commodities or services related to furnitures, home-use devices, interior design and domestic decoration, that is, things you have to spend money on before you move into your new house.

Comment: So it's 'fixtures and fittings'?

Comment: @Pedroski You can comprehend the sentence in this way. 家装 is short for 家庭装修, which is just decoration. But for 家居, in my opinion, it's a little hard to find a direct and accurate translation. It includes the actual things you need to add to your house such as furnitures, and something else such as the environment and management, I mean the management of the building, the duty of the janitor.

Comment: @Pedroski IMO the closest English word for 家居 is 'home' when it's used as the name of a category such as in a store. 家居 spans across furnishing, fittings, decoration, household goods, kitchen supplies, bedroom necessities, etc.